# Getting data from a weird array

Tags: arrays, facebook, api

I am trying to get som data out of a Facebook array. It has allways worked earlier, but I have problems now for some reason.

```
$json=json_decode($string,true);
$from= $json['0']['data']['from']['name'];
```

The array output:

```
{    "data": [
      {
         "id": "XXX",
         "from": {
            "name": "Random name",
            "id": "ID123321"
         },
```

And a lot of different parameters and arrays bellow.

What is wrong with my `$from` variable?

Answer (score 0):

It coud be that there is more than one element in `data`

Try using `$from= $json['0']['data'][0]['from']['name'];`